# How do I open or close a folder without reloading the entire Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-editor

It is possible to open or close folder in VSCode **without reload**?

It a little strange that program must have reload if we just open folder....

In addition, this is a problem if you have previously opened other tabs without any folder

GIF below:
[image]

I have some habits from Sublime, where it wasn't a big problem.
I just opened the folder and it was added - nothing simpler.
I can't understand this behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a response from their Github repo

Unfortunately

> Currently not possible

Link here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/70901#issuecomment-475256679